# Type Error: Not an Integer phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I just installed phonegap with its dependences but when I try to run

**phonegap create myproject**

I get the following message:

```
TypeError: Not an integer
    at Object.fs.writeSync (fs.js:537:18)
    at Function.writeFileSync [as sync] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/write-file-atomic/index.js:114:10)
    at Object.create.all.set (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:62:21)
    at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:11)
    at new Insight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:38:34)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/src/telemetry.js:37:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Note: I use a linux debian based distro

Comment: just update your node and phonegap version and it will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot.That worked!

Answer (score 0):

just update your node and phonegap version and it will be work.